# JEditorPane embedded images cannot be displayed

Tags: java, image, swing, jeditorpane

Good evening,

I've been trying to display html code in a JEditorPane with embedded images. The code for the image that I receive is the following:

```
<img title="1909-yamaha-nemesis2.jpg" alt="1909-yamaha-nemesis2.jpg" src="cid:ii_12d7652d11e8d9a6">
```

As you can imagine, I cannot display the image, any idea? I suspect it should be the CID codification.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://java-sl.com/tip_local_images.html
You can use the same approach and place your image in the local cache.

Comment: Thanks Stanislav for answering, but what I really need is to get the image from inside the body of the html text, not to load an image from a local folder or create it dynamically.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no simple answer. HTMLEditorKit can't process this. You can add custom processing for the tag and check whether src starts from cid. If yes you can place images in local cache and use them.

Comment: Stanislav, I could resolve the issue by following your advice, just get the images from a local sorce, I mean, I downloaded the images and then included them in the source. Just replace the src of the image by 

    file://<absoulte-path-to-the-image>" 

and then replace the original html tag entirely.  

Thank man! ;)